# Avoid UAC prompt for silent install

Tags: command-line, uac

I created a Task (setup.exe) using Task scheduler which when run doesn't ask for **Elevated Permissions** prompt. I have checked "Run with Highest Privileges"
See screenshot

[image: Windows Task Scheduler]

However,
for scheduling a task using command-line, I created a Task using

**schtasks /create /tn "T2" /tr "C:\Users\kamal\Downloads\SGuardian\ds.exe" /sc ONCE /SD 08/10/2015 /ST 05:29**

It always prompts for elevated permissions.

I also tried adding a /ru SYSTEM

This doesn't prompt for elevated permissions but it runs the task in non-interactive mode (background) which I don't want.

What is the way to create the task in **COMMAND LINE** for local account DEV-03\kamal and Run with highest privileges. ( as shown in screen shot )

Please suggest

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can add /RL highest and it will check the box. This will require you to be elevated though